# Android Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not 
    called Looper.prepare()
```

I also tried running on the UI Thread and using Looper.prepare with a Post to itself to cancel.

My structure is as follow:

```
public class WebPageActivity extends Activity {
    int scan_NOK = 0;
    int scan_OK = 0;
    Date scan_time = new Date();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    // SOME CODE TO START MY VOID FUNCTION

    void beginListenForData(){
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {                
               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
               {
                    // SOME CODE

                    if( data.length() != 40 && data.length() != 36) {
                        errorSound();
                        scan_NOK++;
                    } else {
                        scan_OK++;
                    }

                    WebPageActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            timer.cancel(); // ERROR HERE
                            timer = new Timer(); // OR HERE

                            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                               public void run() {
                                  if(scan_NOK + scan_OK > 1) {
                                      AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebPageActivity.this);

                                      dlgAlert.setMessage("Scans \r\nOK: " + scan_OK + "\r\nNot OK: " + scan_NOK);
                                      dlgAlert.setTitle("Scans");
                                      dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                      dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                                      dlgAlert.create().show();               
                                  }
                               }
                            }, 2500);
                        }
                    });
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer task runs on a different thread. Cannot update ui from non ui thread.
use `runOnUiThread`.

Make sure you show the alert dialog from a ui thread.

Comment: Please look into my code, I already use `runOnUiThread`. Also tried it withouth `classname.this`

Comment: @Niels you have runOnUithread in which you have a timertask in which you show alert dialog. Now use `runOnUiThread` only for alert dialog

Comment: THank you I added an extra `runOnUiThread` for the dialog and it works now. Been trying for a while now. Thank you! Can not accept the awnser withing 10 minutes.

Comment: @Niels also what does this do `errorSound();` Anything updating ui there??

Comment: That is generating a new Thread where I call the ToneGenerator that generates my error sounds.

Comment: @Niels no need `runOnUithread` for timer task. So use `runOnUiThread` for alert dialog only. Also    `Timer timer = new Timer();` and this  `timer.cancel(); 
                            timer = new Timer();`. Declaration and initialize once.

Comment: I need to cancel the timer, I read that you need to reinitialize the timer if you cancel it.